# Extracting Elements from JSON

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a function that returns JSON, and the return type is this:

```
map[string]interface{}
```

In my particular case, I know that the returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "someNumber": 1,
  "someString": "ee",
  "someArray": [
    "stringInArray",
    {
      "anotherNumber": 100,
      "anotherString": "asdf",
      "yetAnotherString": "qwer"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the value of "stringInArray" and also "anotherString". I've searched for solutions for example from [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/json) and [blog.golang.org](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) but I've not been successful.

For example, given that **res** is the json returned from the function call, I tried this (from the go blog):

```
var f interface{}
b := []byte(`res` )
err2 := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
if err2!=nil{
    log.Fatalf("Err unmarshalling: %v", err2)
}

m := f.( map[string]interface{} )

for k, v := range m {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
    case int:
        fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        for i, u := range vv {
            fmt.Println(i, u)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
    }
}
```

(I know the above would not do exactly what I want but it is a start.)
But when code execution hits **b := []byte(`res` )**, I get this error:

```
Err unmarshalling: invalid character 'r' looking for beginning of value
```

What is the most efficient method / best practice for obtaining the values? I'm open to any solution, not necessarily the approach above.

@sydnash Here is the code I promised in my response to your comment:

```
type LoginResponse2 struct {

    id float64
    jsonrpc string
    result struct {
        token string
        details struct {
            a float64
            b string
            c float64
        }
    }   
}

var resStruct2 LoginResponse2
// Convert result to json
b, _ :=json.Marshal(res)
fmt.Println( string(b) )
// results of Println:
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[ "myToken",{"a":someNumber,"b":"some string","c":someOtherNumber} ] }


// Unmarshall json into struct
err2 := json.Unmarshal(b, &resStruct2)
if err2 != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error unmarshalling json: %v", err)
}

fmt.Println("Here is json unmarshalled into a struct")
fmt.Println( resStruct2 )
// results of Println
{0  { {0  0}}}
```

Comment: The string `"res"` isn't valid json, so you can't unmarshal from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use b := []byte(res) instead b :=[]byte[`res`] and res should be a json string or []byte.  `res` is not a legal json format.

this information maybe help you:
To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

bool, for JSON booleans

float64, for JSON numbers

string, for JSON strings

[]interface{}, for JSON arrays

map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects

nil for JSON null

you can see there is no int but float64 for JSON numbers.

Comment: Thanks, sydnash. The first problem I have to solve is this: **res** is **map[string]interface{}** and not valid json. How do I convert to json?

Comment: Through a very verbose process of iterating over the `res` object I was able to extract values and populate a struct (which is what I want to do based on @miltonb's answer about unmarshalling json into the struct), but I have a feeling that I'm just duplicating what the `json.Unmarshall` function does. So I would still be interested in knowing if there is a fairly clean straightforward way to convert the `map[string]interface{}` to json. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to convert map to json?   if all element value type is builtin type, this example may help you.   https://play.golang.org/p/rpy1Txz6wK

Comment: I used `json.Marshal` and it worked, but when I tried unmarshalling into a struct, the unmarshalling failed. I think the problem is that the json includes a tuple but my struct does not reflect the tuple because I don't know how to model a tuple in a struct. Can you advise on how to do so? I will edit my question to show the code I'm using.

Comment: Oh, first your struct's field name must be upper case; then array in json is not to decode to struct, but we can do it in some specially way.
see this code. https://play.golang.org/p/WtA84_Y9Kn

Comment: Thanks again. I have a question. After unmarshalling into the struct, I extracted the token and be default it was enclosed in quotation marks. It's fairly easy to remove the quotation marks, but is there a way to prevent it from getting wrapped in quotation marks to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to unmarshal json in the docs on golang packages [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).  Essentially your problem is that the un-marshal expects to be putting the json into `type`.  So your code must declare a type that represents the `json` you are converting from.

Example of the json and the declared type from the linked example:

```
var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
    {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
    {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
]`)
type Animal struct {
    Name  string
    Order string
}
```

Once you define the type it should all fall into place.

Comment: Thanks, miltonb. If I understand you correctly, I must create a struct that represents the json

Comment: You can also use the [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) library if the schema of your input JSON changes in unpredictable ways.